# Class MyThread extends Thread. Why we can use Surfaceholder, Context and Handler as parameters?

Tags: java, android, constructor

I find the following Thread with parameters in the Android website.
I search many forum and tutorial and still don't understand.

My question is why we can use Surfaceholder, Context and Handler as parameters in Thread:

e.g.

```
Class MyThread extends Thread {
public Mythread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context, Handler handler){
....
}
...
```

However, the following Thread classes are listed in Android website only:

```
Thread() 
Allocates a new Thread object.

Thread(Runnable target) 
Allocates a new Thread object.

Thread(Runnable target, String name) 
Allocates a new Thread object.

Thread(String name) 
Allocates a new Thread object.

Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target) 
Allocates a new Thread object.

Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name) 
Allocates a new Thread object so that it has target as its run object, has the specified name as its name, and belongs to the thread group referred to by group.

Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize) 
Allocates a new Thread object so that it has target as its run object, has the specified name as its name, and belongs to the thread group referred to by group, and has the specified stack size.

Thread(ThreadGroup group, String name) 
Allocates a new Thread object.
```

Comment: `MyThread` defines its own constructor with the 3 parameters you mentioned. It will use those internally for its own purposes which are not related to the `Thread` parent class. This is why the `Thread` parent class doesn't mention any of those.

Comment: Do you mean we can create our own parameters for existing Thread Class?

Comment: Kind of. You can define your own parameters when you make your own class. In this case, `MyThread` inherits from the `Thread` class. More information about inheritance: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html